# As javascript detect when a form post is canceled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As javascript detect when a form post is canceled using the button "Stop loading this page" or STOP button in the browser?

Comment: try adding more info, people will downvote if you don't and that will demotive you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the post action is taken from the browser, the request is gone off to the server land, thus even with clicking the stop button on the browser won't actually "cancel" the form from being posted. Since there is no "canceling" of the post action, no javascript can detect such non-existing events.